# C++/Eclipse Shared Library: Why can g++ not find this library?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am following the instructions on
http://tayefeh.wordpress.com/2009/07/06/creating-and-using-a-c-shared-library-with-eclipse-cdt-galileo-and-gnu-c-compiler-and-linker/
to build a shared library.

I have got to Step II, bullet point 16 but my attempts to build the project fail with the following error:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project UseDLL ****

make all 
Building target: UseDLL
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L"/home/ken/workspace/testlib/Debug" -o"UseDLL"  ./src/UseDLL.o   -ltestlib -l/home/ken/workspace/testlib/Debug
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/ken/workspace/testlib/Debug
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [UseDLL] Error 1
```

Can anyone advise why the build is failing?  The directory does exist and `ls` shows

```
[ken@localhost Debug]$ ls /home/ken/workspace/testlib/Debug/
libtestlib.so  TestClass.o
```

If it helps, I am running CentOS 6.3.

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this:

> -l/home/ken/workspace/testlib/Debug

It makes `g++` look for a library of that name.